# Connexion Intermittence: MongoDB from Php7.4

Tags: php, mongodb, intermittent

I have problems with intermittence in connection to mongodb since PHP 7.4. I don't understand why sometimes it fails to connect to ReplicaSet. What can I do ?
I leave the log of my application below.

```
[18:58] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64bf99167c2a42530a2dbd97 has finished
[18:58] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72
[18:58] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72 has finished
[19:00] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64e61827874b0d115f5797d3
[19:00] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64e61827874b0d115f5797d3 has finished
[19:00] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64c37883921ed7598d54a694
[19:00] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64c37883921ed7598d54a694 has finished
[19:00] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64bf99167c2a42530a2dbd97
[19:00] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64bf99167c2a42530a2dbd97 has finished
[19:00] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72
[19:00] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72 has finished
[19:02] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64e61827874b0d115f5797d3
[19:02] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64e61827874b0d115f5797d3 has finished
[19:02] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64c37883921ed7598d54a694
[19:02] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64c37883921ed7598d54a694 has finished
[19:02] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64bf99167c2a42530a2dbd97
[19:02] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64bf99167c2a42530a2dbd97 has finished
[19:02] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72
[19:02] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72 has finished
[19:02] [Worker 1] [132] An error has ocurred on Process 64b920317c2a42530a2dbd72. Error Details: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set) on vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php line 487 Trace: #0 vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php(487): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->selectServer()
#1 vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(687): MongoDB\select_server()
#2 libs/Mongodb/Collection.php(412): MongoDB\Collection->findOne()
#3 models/UserCollection.php(242): App\Libraries\Mongodb\Collection::findFirst()
#4 config/Injector.php(76): App\Collections\UserCollection::findFirst()
#5 models/CoreCollection.php(182): App\Collections\CoreCollection::getUser()
#6 models/ProcessCollection.php(454): App\Collections\CoreCollection->save()
#7 tasks/ProcessTask.php(112): App\Collections\ProcessCollection->save()
#8 [internal function]: App\Tasks\ProcessTask->App\Tasks\{closure}()
#9 vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(1055): call_user_func()
#10 [internal function]: PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->basic_deliver()
#11 vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(220): call_user_func()
#12 vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(374): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->dispatch()
#13 services/Queue/Worker.php(58): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->wait()
#14 tasks/ProcessTask.php(143): App\Services\Queue\Worker->consume()
#15 [internal function]: App\Tasks\ProcessTask->consumeAction()
#16 [internal function]: Phalcon\Cli\Dispatcher->callActionMethod()
#17 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher\AbstractDispatcher->dispatch()
#18 run(27): Phalcon\Cli\Console->handle()
#19 {main} 
[19:04] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64e61827874b0d115f5797d3
[19:04] [Worker 1] [109] Process with id 64e61827874b0d115f5797d3 has finished
[19:04] [Worker 1] [88] Start processing Process with id 64c37883921ed7598d54a694
```

Comment: There is literally nothing about the error in the logs - it just says that you are running a phalcon cli subscriber to RabbitMQ and it fails to connect to mongo db on an attempt to save a ProcessTask.  Check corresponding db logs at the time of an error. if there is nothing obvious there, I'm afraid you will need to share some code and describe your architecture or seek professional help to debug it in-situ. SO format is not quite suitable for such broad requests for help.

Comment: The best anyone can provide based off what you posted here in generic troubleshooting advice. I'd add to Alex's comment that it's worth checking your PHP apps logs as well, and review your connection time out/network connectivity, but again, nothing more than basic troubleshooting.